# How to loop all files in current directory and move it to a folder named as the first word of the file?

Tags: bash

This is how i'm trying, after searching how to do each individual step. But nothing happens after running the bash file. What is wrong with my code ?

```
#!/bin/bash
for filename in * ; # This should  loop all files in the current directory
do mv filename /| head -n1 | cut -d " " -f1   # and this should create a directory in the same folder, if it dosent exists, name it as the first word of file name, and move the file to the directory
```

Input example :
files inside directory `/dir` :

```
'2013 test one' '2014 test two' '2015 test three'
```

Desired output example :
folders inside directory `/dir` :

```
'2013' '2014' '2015'
```

And
the file '2013 test one' is inside folder '2013',

the file '2014 test two' is inside folder '2014',

and '2015 test three' is inside folder '2015'

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired result for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for something like this:

```
for f in ./*; do
  d=${f%% *}
  mkdir -p "$d" && mv "$f" "$d"
done
```